# UITableView does not show data after LoadData call

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios5

I'm having an issue with the UITableView object updating after load.  I have a feeling it has to do with the async data, but I'm at a loss.  The table delegate and datasource is set to the UIView (CartViewController).

.h

```
@interface CartViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSDictionary *myCart;
    NSArray *myCartItems;
    UITableView *tableView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *myCart;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *myCartItems;
- (IBAction)RemoveFromCart:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0)

#import "CartViewController.h"
#import "VariablesStore.h"

@implementation CartViewController
@synthesize myCart,myCartItems;
@synthesize tableView;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[VariablesStore sharedInstance] CartURL]]];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

          [self.tableView reloadData];

       });

    });

}


- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{

    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSDictionary* cart = [json objectForKey:@"Cart"];
    myCart = cart;

    NSArray *itemList = [cart objectForKey:@"CartItemList"];
    myCartItems = itemList;

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    return [myCartItems count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


    UILabel *skuNum = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    NSDictionary *cartItem = [myCartItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", cartItem); // returns the cart item
    NSLog(@"SkuFormatted: %@", [cartItem valueForKey:@"SKUFormatted"]); //shows the sku correctly
    [skuNum setText:[cartItem valueForKey:@"SKUFormatted"]];
    NSLog(@"skuNum:%@", skuNum.text); //shows (null) for the sku


    return cell;
}



@end
```

I do almost the exact same thing on another view, and have compared, but I'm not seeing any difference that would cause the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your table get reloaded before data from URL arives. Try to reload data in thread where you requesting data from URL. Try to remove second dispatch_async.

Comment: I removed the second dispatch_async and nothing.  I even removed the first dispatch_async and just got the data on viewdidload, still nothing.  The data is returning with the expected results (I can see it when I NSLog it).

Comment: Try to put `NSLog(@"Number of objects returned: %i", [myCartItems count]);` before return, in `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection` section and check in log if there is something else than 0;

Comment: It gets called twice, once on the initial view load and once when I call the reload on the table view.  The first comes back with 0 as I would expect since I haven't loaded the data.  The second comes back with the expected amount (in this case 1).

Comment: OK and now try to dump to NSLog data in cartItem in numberOfRowsInSection under NSDictionary *cartItem. Just something like `NSLog(@"Dictionary : %@", cartItem);` if there are data to be displayed in cell compositioning.

Comment: The cart item has data.  I did find something interesting. it looks like the setText is not working.  Inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath I have added what I do to set up each cell.  The setText on the UILabel doesn't set the text.  I have added the code above to show what I do

Comment: Remove whole section with UILabel and set text to cell like `cell.textLabel.text = [cartItem valueForKey:@"SKUFormatted"];`
It should work. Then, if it works, if you need compose your own cell, you have to add subviews to cell contentView.

Comment: I found the issue.  I didn't set the Identifier on the cell.  I'm going to accept the answer.  Even though it was my own stupidity, you helped my step through and find the issue.  Thanks for your time!!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all of your IBOutlets connected in interface builder.

Comment: The IBOutlets are connected (only the one for the tableView).